# Log stash update action fails with 404 status

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to parse some sample file with fixed width fields through log stash and then put that parsed data into elastic search. I don't want the duplicates to be put into elastic search and to achieve this I am configuring that the action is update and specifically specifying the id field for document id. But when I start my log stash it fails with an error as shown below:

```
Failed action.  {:status=>404, :action=>["update", {:_id=>"RECORD_CODE", :_index=>"transactions", :_type=>"lot13", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x389f17de @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x5dd5606b @store={"path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "retry_count"=>0}, @lut={"[path]"=>[{"path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "retry_count"=>0}, "path"]}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, @metadata={"path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "retry_count"=>0}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x78c1600a @store={"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "host"], "path"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "path"], "message"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "message"], "RECORD_CODE"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "RECORD_CODE"], "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"], "REG_NUMBER"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "REG_NUMBER"], "DATA_TYPE"=>[{"message"=>"878979797978779779797978", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-11-26T12:43:06.677Z", "host"=>"priyas-MacBook-Pro.local", "path"=>"/Users/priya/sample.log", "RECORD_CODE"=>"8", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"=>"789797", "REG_NUMBER"=>"979787797797", "DATA_TYPE"=>"979"}, "DATA_TYPE"]}>>], :response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"transactions", "_type"=>"lot13", "_id"=>"RECORD_CODE", "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"document_missing_exception", "reason"=>"[lot13][RECORD_CODE]: document missing", "shard"=>"-1", "index"=>"transactions"}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

The content of my config file is:

```
# The # character at the beginning of a line indicates a comment. Use
# comments to describe your configuration.
input {
    file {
    path => "/Users/priya/sample.log"
    start_position => beginning 
    sincedb_path => "/Users/priya/sample-sincedb-file"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" => "(?<RECORD_CODE>.{1})(?<SEQUENCE_NUMBER>.{6})(?<REG_NUMBER>.{12})(?<DATA_TYPE>.{3})"}
    }


}

output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => localhost
       index => transactions
       document_type => lot13
       document_id => RECORD_CODE
 #      template => "/Users/priya/template.json"
 #      template_name => "sample_template"
       action => update 

    }
    stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

And when I search in elastic search, nothing is retrieved - so clearly data is not getting into elastic search. Could some one please help me with this?

Thanks and regards,
Priya

Answer (score 3):

Here error is:
 `"error"=>{"type"=>"document_missing_exception", "reason"=>"[lot13][RECORD_CODE]: document missing", "shard"=>"-1", "index"=>"transactions"`

So the update fails when the document is missing.

You need to use `doc_as_upsert = true` along with `action => update` to create a new document with source if document_id doesn’t exist in Elasticsearch.